# What is a company allowed to do with investors funds?

Tags: investing, stock-markets, financial-literacy, shares

Imagine there are two companies. Company A invests £1m in Company B. Company B stock price goes up. Company B now has £1m and decides to Invest in company A.

Company A stock price goes up and with the newly invested £1m invests again in company B etc etc

What are the rules to stop this false increase in company stock price?

Comment: Stock price going up doesn't mean the company has more money.

Comment: If you're suggesting that A just goes out and buys £1m worth of existing shares of B, where it breaks down is that B doesn't actually get anything directly from that.

Comment: Welcome new user, I fear you are mixing-up a lot of different concepts.  If I "buy shares" of Apple, Apple does not get one cent. It doesn't affect Apple in *any way*.  Conversely, I don't even know how I could "invest" $1m in Apple - what I mean is NOT buying shares, but literally investing it in the company.  For example, if I own a restaurant, you can "invest" $1m in that business: you either give me or loan me the $1m and I use it to buy more real estate, more steaks, hire staff, etc.  But that's not meaningfdul with a public company like Apple (or "B" in your example).

Comment: @MarkEvans I think as a starting point, you might want to step back from some of the assumptions you have about how much trickery you think there is in public financial markets. You seem to be expecting that fraud exists, and that may be framing how you interpret the answers being provided. In the scope of what you are talking about, you can have some confidence that current reporting regulations definitely try to prevent the type of manipulation you are looking for.

Comment: Hi ‘Eh’ Bacon, just a newbie here trying to understand the world of investing. I found this page earlier which I think might be useful for me to understand just where does the money actually go and to whom. 

https://investsomemoney.com/when-i-buy-stock-where-does-my-money-go-other-questions/

Answer (score 2):

A modified form of the @glglgl example:

1. `Company B` issues new shares (thus diluting existing ownership).
2. `Company A` can buy them for £1m cash, thus injecting new money into `Company B`.
3. Now `Company B` has a £1m asset of type "cash".
4. For whatever foolish reason, `Company B` uses that £1m asset to buy £1m of share of `Company A` stock.
5. Thus, `Company B` no longer has a £1m asset of type "cash", but now has a £1m asset of type "shares" in Company A.

As you can see, there's no magical money expansion.  `B` has £1m more in assets than it did at the beginning of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic doesn't match exactly, because the stock price going up isn't going to happen (because, why should it?)

But let's simplify it a bit:

Imagine there are two companies. For the sake of simplicity, Company A has £1m, Company B has nothing (or nearly nothing, or maybe just £1).

Company A invests these £1m in Company B. For the sake if this, B creates new shares. As B's owners' part of the company is diluted, they have to agree to this, but let's assume they do.

Then B has £1m of cash and invests them in A. In order to make this happen, A creates new shares (the owners agreeing), and is now worth £2m.

At this point, the following happens:

A is worth £2m. It has £1m of cash and £1m of shares in B.
A belongs to its original owners (50%) and to B (50%).

B is worth £1m. All this consists of £1m of shares in A (and £1 in cash, but let's ignore that).
B belongs to A (£1m) and to its original owner (£1, but let's ignore that as well).

Now what would be the purpose of doing so?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am however still a little confused on how these things work. 

In the beginning of the example there was only £1m of “real” money. However at the end of your example [A] is now worth £2m and [B] is worth £1m. 

How did we manage to go from £1m to £3m? When only £1m of real money exists?

Comment: @MarkEvans There's an Economics concept known as the velocity of money that comes into play here. Effectively, even though there's only £1m actual cash floating around, that cash has been spent twice, leaving £2m of "assets" behind. Those assets reflect the value of each company, which is the sum of many things including cash balance. This hypothetical leaves both companies values at £1m of "value" not tied to anything each, and £1m of cash.